# Deinit method called automatically when its instance is initialised and delegate is set to some view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, deinit

When I initialise the ABCViewController instance to push this controller, like I did it here.

```
private func showABCController() {
      let storyBoard = UIStoryboard (
            name: "PaymentView", bundle: Bundle(for: ABCViewController.self)
        )
      var abcViewController =  storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ABCViewController") as! ABCViewController
      abcViewController.delegate = self
}
```

The denit method of the view controller is called just after the delegate is set to self even before I push the view controller  :-

```
//ABCViewController.swift
    import UIKit
    protocol ABCViewControllerDelegate : class{
        func backButtonPressed()
    }
    class ABCViewController: UIViewController {
        weak var delegate : ABCViewControllerDelegate?
        override func loadView() {
            super.loadView()
            print("loadView")
        }
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

        deinit {
            delegate?.backButtonPressed()
        }
        /*
        // MARK: - Navigation

        // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
            // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        }
        */

    }
```

My concern why deinit is called? Here I have observed the other methods such as loadview and viewdidload is not called. So before the controller is loaded into the memory how can it be de-initialised.

Comment: I tried running your code and I don't see any issue with it. There might be something else resulting in `deinit` call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dig deeper into how ARC works.
In your case, you lost reference to your ViewController strictly after showABCController() method done its job. 
Possible solutions:

1. Push your VC from showABCController() method
2. Keep strong reference to abcViewController outside from method and don't forget to release it after exactly pushing it

Comment: @HimanDhawan tried what exactly? Can you provide a bit more code please with your test cases